# Input to a directive using double curly bracers not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've written this directive that renders some stars using d3.js. It works fine when I give it hard coded inputs but when I give it input from my scope it doesn't work. This is parts of my directive (that exhibits the same behaviour):

```
   app.directive('stars', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                width: "@",
                height: "@",
                maxStars: "@",
                filled: "@"
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(attrs);
                console.log(attrs.filled);
            }
        }
  });
```

I call my directive like this:

```
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="Mainctrl">
    <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="agent in data">
                <td stars width="200" height="100" max-stars="5" filled="{{agent.ratings.avg}}"></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Printing out attrs give me (among other values):

```
filled: "4"
height: "100"
maxStars: "5"
stars: ""
width: "200"
```

While printing attrs.filled gives me 'undefined'.

I find it really wierd that I can clearly see that the object attrs has a value for the key 'filled' but when I try to access it I get 'undefined'.

Comment: Could you set up a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) / [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FbvIkUWk0aPJa9WsVFc1?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, I can! I'll get right on that.

Comment: **A general note:** when doing `console.log(x)` you get a link to `x` in the console. When clicking that link later, the `x` you see is what it is at that *later* time, not what it was when printed. This can be wildly misleading. In such cases, also do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(x))` at the first place.

Comment: Here is a plunker that reproduces the error: http://plnkr.co/edit/lqTHu3iOeOajwRnoiALr

I made this from the plunker @boindiil made and realized it worked fine with angular 1.3. So I guess the solution to this is to up me version of angular.

Answer (score 0):

It's been answered in comments to the original post.